# Swift Loading localized View from XIB

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, storyboard, xib

I have an app with localized Storyboard and collection view in it. To be precise FSPagerView. Standard localization works fine (Base). Now, instead of calling register(FSPagerViewCell.self ...), I am loading my own view from XIB file by calling:

`pagerView.register(UINib(nibName: slide, bundle: Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: slide)`

or with the bundle equal nil which for me, works the same way.

My problem is that the loaded XIB is always in English even if the rest of the app in Russian.

I tried to delete the application from the simulator, clear the project, restarting Xcode, but nothing helps. Again, Storyboard was localized without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way?.

pagerView.register(UINib(nibName: slide, bundle:Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: slide)

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work for me. But what did work is this:
In slide properties, I switched from Localizable string to interface builder. It did not work before when I passed nil for bundle param but now after sending Bundle.main it works. Not sure how optimal it is to make new XIB file for translation but nothing else did work.